# python web framework -- dynamic routes to extension modules

Tags: python, bottle, restful-url

I'm exploring the use of python's bottle web framework.  The web application must be extensible.  That is, I will have a folder like "some/path/extensions/" into which future developers should be able to place extensions to this application.  So for example: if the extension is called "treelayout" (with its own set of html files, js files etc, these files would be placed in .../.../extensions/treelayout/ folder.  My goal is to have a url router that looks something like:

```
@GET("/some/path/extensions/:module/:func/:params")
def callmodule(module, func, params):
    #D = dictionary made out of variable number of params.
    #Then call module.func(D)  <== How can I do this given that module and func are strings?
```

Example, someone could call "h++p: //.../treelayout/create/maxnodes/100/fanout/10/depth/3" and this would call the new extension  treelayout.create( {maxnodes:100, fanout:10, depth:3} ).

Any idea if this is possible to do with bottle or any other python framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python language can map string variables to loaded modules & methods.

```py
import sys 

@GET("/some/path/extensions/:module/:func/:params")
def callmodule(module, func, params):
    D = dict(params)
    # Pull module instance from systems stack
    moduleInstance = sys.modules[module]
    # Grab method from module
    functionInstance = getattr(moduleInstance,func)
    # Pass "D" variable to function instance
    functionInstance(D)
```

Other great examples can be found in the answers to the following questions

- [Python: Convert string into function name; getattr or equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738687/python-convert-string-into-function-name-getattr-or-equal)
- [listing all functions in a python module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139180/listing-all-functions-in-a-python-module)

Comment: Thanks a lot emcconville.  I think this will definitely fit my needs.